# glutCreateWindow(...) resetting my enabled flags?

Tags: c++, opengl

Here's my initialization code:

```
const int WIN_HEIGHT = 640;
const int WIN_WIDTH = 640;
void main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);

    /* lines in question */
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glutInitWindowSize(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL");
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(HandleInput);
    Initialize();

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

So, most of that code is pretty boilerplate for a basic 3D program. The problem is, if I put all the `glEnable()` lines before `glutCreateWindow()` they are reset. It's an easy enough fix to move them after creating the window (I moved them to my own `Initialize()` function), but why would `glutCreateWindow()` disable these?

Comment: You were given the answer already. But keep in mind: OpenGL state should be set in the drawing function (and only there). I know, most tutorials do it otherwise, but in the long term it makes things so much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's because a [context](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_context) has not yet been created before your call to `glutCreateWindow()`. You are then able to set them after one is created, as can be interpreted from the following text:

> In order for any OpenGL commands to work, a context must be current; all OpenGL commands affect the state of whichever context is current.

Since there was no context (or an old, invalid one), your calls to `glInit()` don't affect the current window's context.

Answer (score 1):

Because `glEnable` is being done to the *current* window. Once you call `glutCreateWindow` you've made a new window and replaced your current one with it. This new window has a new opengl context. After creating a new window you can go ahead and enable and modify it's context as you want.

Reference: http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node16.html